# How do I extract X,Y screen coordinates from listener thread pynput?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pynput

I'm unable to access values for screen X,Y coordinates when using mouse.Listener (Pynput)

I am trying to build a screen capture tool using pynput, Pillow (ImageGrab) and OpenCV (cv2) and need to store X,Y screen coordinates in separate variables.

I've tired returning x,y variables from within the on_click() function and tried assigning the mouse.Listener (threading function) to a variable with no luck (just returns )

The function works correctly and accurately displays the X,Y coordinates on pressing and releasing the mouse.

Is there a way to store the X,Y coordinates obtained on mouse pressing and release ?

Mac OSX 10.13.6, Python 3.7.3.

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):

    if pressed:
        print(f"start_pos = ({x},{y})")
    elif not pressed:
        print(f"end_pos = ({x},{y})")
        return False

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
```

I cannot store the values from the output thread object.

Answer (score 0):

If you import Controller from `pynput` and use it as such;

```
mouse = Controller()
mouse.position
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many Thanks. Unfortunately, I get an error message when combining Controller with the Listener function. 
I ended up with a workaround, creating an empty list variable in the global space then updating in the function with x,y co-ordinates.